# How to predict a simple sequence using seq2seq from tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I've recently started working with tensorflow so I'm still struggling with basics.

I wanted to create simple seq2seq prediction.

- Input is list of numbers between 0 and 1.
- Output is first number from
  list and the rest of the numbers multiplied by first.

I managed to evaluate model performance and optimize weights. 
The thing I've been struggling is how to make predictions with trained model.

```
 model_outputs, states = seq2seq.basic_rnn_seq2seq(encoder_inputs,
                                                  decoder_inputs,
                                                  rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(data_point_dim, state_is_tuple=True))
```

In order to generate model_outputs I need both input and output values for the model, which is good for evaluation but in prediction I only have input values. I'm guessing I need to do something with states but I'm unsure how to transform them into sequence of floats.

Full code is available here
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/be405097927758acca158666854600a2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're training, you give the decoder input at each decoder timestep as the desired output.
When testing, you do not have the desired output, so the best you can do is sample an output. This will be the input to the next timestep.

TLDR; Feed in the decoder output at each timestep as the input for the next timestep.

**Edit: Some TF codes**

The **basic_rnn_seq2seq** function **return**s **rnn_decoder**(decoder_inputs, enc_states[-1], cell)

let's look at the **rnn_decoder**:
def rnn_decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state, cell, loop_function=**None**,
                scope=None):
  ....

**loop_function**: if not None, this function will be applied to i-th output
      in order to generate i+1-th input, and decoder_inputs will be ignored,
      except for the first element ("GO" symbol). This can be used for decoding,
      but also for training to emulate http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03099v2.pdf.

During decoding, you need to set this loop_function=**True**

I recommend looking at the translate.py file in Tensorflow seq2seq library to see how this is handled.

Comment: if I understand correctly going by that solution, I would ignore states variable and just use output in session.run(output, feed_dict=feed) to get results?  

Shouldn't there be a way to use states in this process? I've been working with scikit-learn and I was hoping there is  a way to create something like model.predict method

Comment: Added further clarification but yes, you will ignore the hidden state because the hidden states are exactly that: They're hidden states that are already being used to create the final output of the RNN anyway. As far as code change goes, I recommend taking a look at the seq2seq wmt example provided by Tensorflow. I believe you do have to change the output feed.

Comment: I am also struggling to get something like this to work. Could anyone  provide a simple working example that does what is described in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by user4383691 is incomplete. 
I have the same problem, and after digging into the rnn_decoder, found this: The model *applies* the *loop_fn* to the ith output, so **True** makes no sense as it is not a function.
You should make a function which could take in the ith output and return the i+1 th output. I am still in the process of making such a function, and will update as soon as it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L145):

```
prev = None    for i, inp in enumerate(decoder_inputs):
     if loop_function is not None and prev is not None:
       with variable_scope.variable_scope("loop_function", reuse=True):
         inp = loop_function(prev, i)
     if i > 0:
       variable_scope.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
     output, state = cell(inp, state)
     outputs.append(output)
     if loop_function is not None:
       prev = output
```

The loop enumerates the decoder_inputs whether you are training with the decoder_inputs provided or testing without the inputs. It is because the decoder_inputs is replaced by the output of the loop_function(in the fourth line in the above snippet) while testing.

Usually you can fill the dec_inputs with end_ids like [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/textsum/batch_reader.py#L189).

```
  while len(dec_inputs) < self._hps.dec_timesteps:
    dec_inputs.append(end_id)
  while len(targets) < self._hps.dec_timesteps:
    targets.append(end_id)
```